# I want to compile apps for Ubuntu-Touch. What are some good resources?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, compiling, arm

I have an Acquarius M10. I want to try to compile x11 apps for use on my tablet. I am especially thinking of things like xournal.

What are some good resources for me to start learning about how to do this? Is there a community already engaged in this? Where can I find out more?